# Recyclerview - Sorting not working after searching an 'Arraylist'

Tags: android

I am working in an app with 'recyclerview', and I successfully implemented **Search** and **sorting** in it.

Whenever I sort the list before searching something through it, Sorting works. But after searching something, Sorting is not working. I debugged a lot, but was not able to find what's wrong in my code.

For Sorting:

```
private void sortArrayList() {
        Collections.sort(booksList, new Comparator<BookPojo>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(BookPojo o1, BookPojo o2) {
                return o1.getBookname().compareTo(o2.getBookname());
            }
        });

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void reversesortArrayList() {
        Collections.sort(booksList, new Comparator<BookPojo >() {
            @Override
            public int compare(BookPojo o1, BookPojo o2) {
              return o2.getBookname().compareTo(o1.getBookname());
            }
        });
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

For Searching,

```
void filter(String text) {
        ArrayList<BookPojo > temp = new ArrayList();
        for (BookPojo d : booksList) {

            if (d.getBookname().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                temp.add(d);
            }
        }

        mAdapter.filterList(temp);
    }
```

In Adapter,

```
public void filterList(ArrayList<BookPojo> booklist) {
        this.booklist= booklist;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Sorting works fine before searching the 'recyclerview' through 'edittext'. However, after book name search, My Sorting fails.

Methods are calling all times on button clicks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Can anyone kindly help me out in this issue ?

Comment: What is order of operations? Are you sorting before filtering? If so, that would be the problem. Also it would be useful if you would show us the code from button click.

Comment: While searching you are filtering out items from adapter's list. How have you handled items removed from list after search activity is over?  Your bug lies there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sorted the problem using below code. Both @Seigmeyer and @Om Infowave Developers answers helped me to fix out the issue.  @Jaspreet Kaur answer is awesome for smooth scrolling ! Thanks for all of you guys !

```
void filter(String text) {
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            mAdapter.filterList(booklist);
        } else {
            ArrayList<BookPojo > temp = new ArrayList();
            for (BookPojo d : booklist) {

                if (d.getContactName().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                    temp.add(d);
                }
            }
            mAdapter.filterList(temp);
        }
    }
```

Confused to whom the bounty should go !

Comment: Since you can't reward a bounty to your own answer, leaving the check where it is, will waste it. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) will give you a hint whom to award it.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the problem is this:

When you filter the `booklist` you create a temporary one and assign it to `mAdapter.booklist`:

```
this.booklist = booklist;
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Then, when you want to sort the list you are sorting the *previous* instance of the list, not *current* one (the one that `mAdapter` owns).

I suspect that `mAdapter.booklist = booksList;` before `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in `sortArrayList` and `reverseSortArrayList` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Create one copy of booksList before set filter in booksListMain for filtering function.

```
  booksListMain=new ArrayList();
  booksListMain.addAll(booksList);
```

Update the filter function

```
void filter(String text) {
        booksList.clear();
        if(text.length()==0)
        {
        booksList.addAll(booksListMain);
        }else
        {
            for (BookPojo d : booksListMain) {
                if (d.getBookname().toLowerCase().contains(text)) {
                    booksList.add(d);
                }
            }
        }

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the Following code to display Full List, when search text is
>   empty and create the new list when any text in the search.

```
if (myCustomerInfoArrayList != null && myCustomerInfoArrayList.size() > 0) {
                if (searchText.isEmpty()) {
                    Collections.sort(myArrayList, new CustomerNameSort());

                    SpeedyLinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = 
                    new SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(CustomerActivity.this);
                    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

                    linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(myPosition);

                    myRecyclerViewCustomer.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    myCustomerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(CustomerActivity.this, 
                    myCustomerInfoArrayList, myDataBaseHandler);

                    myRecyclerViewCustomer.setAdapter(myCustomerAdapter);

                    myCustomerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    searchList = new ArrayList<CustomerInfo>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < myCustomerInfoArrayList.size(); i++) {
                        String name = myCustomerInfoArrayList.get(i).getMyFullName();
                        if (name.toLowerCase().contains(searchText)) {
                            CustomerProspectInfo info = myCustomerInfoArrayList.get(i);
                            info.setMyFullName(myCustomerInfoArrayList.get(i).getMyFullName());
                            searchList.add(info);

                        }
                    }
                    Collections.sort(searchList, new CustomerNameSort());

                    SpeedyLinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
                    SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(CustomerActivity.this);
                    linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

                    myRecyclerViewCustomer.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
                    myCustomerAdapter = new CustomerAdapter(CustomerActivity.this, 
                    searchList, myDataBaseHandler);

                    myRecyclerViewCustomer.setAdapter(myCustomerAdapter);
                    myCustomerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }



private class CustomerNameSort implements java.util.Comparator<CustomerProspectInfo> {
        @Override
        public int compare(CustomerInfo lhs, CustomerInfo rhs) {
            String name1, name2;
            name1 = lhs.getMyFullName().toLowerCase().trim();
            name2 = rhs.getMyFullName().toLowerCase().trim();
            return name1.compareTo(name2);
        }
}
```

> This help to increase the speed of recycler view scrolling and you
>   can directly jump to required position.

```
SpeedyLinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(myPosition);   // Position to scroll recycler view.      
myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


SpeedyLinearLayoutManager.class

public class SpeedyLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

        private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH = 2f; //default is 25f (bigger = slower)

        public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
            super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
        }

        public SpeedyLinearLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        }

        @Override
        public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, int position) {

            final LinearSmoothScroller linearSmoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {

                @Override
                public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
                    return SpeedyLinearLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
                }

                @Override
                protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
                    return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
                }
            };

            linearSmoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
            startSmoothScroll(linearSmoothScroller);
        }
    }
```